# Trying to implement a Filter class, but get that erro: The type of class must implement the inherited abstract method

Tags: java, hibernate, session, inheritance, transactions

Even with my methods i need to implement the inherited, but why?

Im only want to get the session, nothing more.

What will happen with The methods that I created if i implement the inherited ones?

code:

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;

import org.hibernate.Filter;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import br.com.javaparaweb.financeiro.util.HibernateUtil;
import javassist.convert.TransformWriteField;

@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"*.jsf"})
public class conexaoHibernateFilter implements Filter {

private SessionFactory sf;

public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException{
    this.sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException{
     Session currentSession = this.sf.getCurrentSession();

     Transaction transaction = null;

        try{
            transaction = currentSession.beginTransaction();
            chain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
            transaction.commit();


            if(currentSession.isOpen()){
                currentSession.close();
            }

        }catch(Throwable ex){
            try{
                if(transaction!=null){
                    transaction.rollback();
                }
            }catch(Throwable tb){
                tb.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

}

public void destroy(){

}
```

}

Error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The type conexaoHibernateFilter must implement the inherited abstract method Filter.getFilterDefinition()
- The type conexaoHibernateFilter must implement the inherited abstract method Filter.setParameterList(String, 
 Object[])
- Breakpoint:conexaoHibernateFilter
- The type conexaoHibernateFilter must implement the inherited abstract method Filter.setParameter(String, Object)
- The type conexaoHibernateFilter must implement the inherited abstract method Filter.validate()
- The type conexaoHibernateFilter must implement the inherited abstract method Filter.setParameterList(String, 
 Collection)
- The type conexaoHibernateFilter must implement the inherited abstract method Filter.getName()
```

Comment: Your class `implements` [`org.hibernate.Filter`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Filter.html), not [`javax.servlet.Filter`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html). Check your `import` statements.

Comment: You also would have gotten more help if you'd used `@Override`.

Answer (score 0):

I have very limited knowledge of what you're trying to do, you can explain a bit more and someone will be able to better help you.

Your class "conexaoHibernateFilter" implements the class "Filter", which contains a few abstract methods. If you want to implement a Filter, you need to implement the methods it describes, or you don't have a complete Filter. Implement the methods that the error message describes. The current methods you already have written will not be affected.

Make sure you're implementing the right class.